# Google Actions game launching with tap does not work

Tags: actions-on-google

I've posted a game on Google Actions named "Jeu du pendu".

When it is launched with the invocation phrase ("Parler avec jeu du pendu" / "Talk to the hangman game") it works normally.
But when it is launched via a tap in the list of games, the conversation ends immediately and the game does not start.

The same problem occurs on the Nest Hub Max or on a smartphone.
On the hub max you just hear 2 beeps. On the smartphone there is a message "Jeu du pendu a quitté la conversation" / "Jeu du pendu has left the conversation"

There is no crash reports of this event in Analytics page, neither in the Api logs.

I reached the Google Support team but they said they can't help with that.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see an invocation happen at this time, even if it's not a crash? What is supposed to happen when you invoke your action?

Comment: I don't see any invocation.
It is supposed to start the game with a welcoming message.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I got the solution.

After searching a little more, I saw a built-in Invocation named 'PLAY_GAME'.
By default it redirects to the 'End Conversation' action.
I changed it to redirect to the 1st game Action like for the Main Invocation (invocation phrase). I re-published the game like that a few days ago.
I just tried now and it works !

It seems that there is no way to test this launching method in the Test console.

Thank for your help.